# Is there a solution being built for those who didn’t register their ERC20 EOS tokens?

Tags: tokens

It’s fair to expect at least a few individuals who hold ERC20 EOS tokens to have missed the message of registration. Some may have registered and lost their EOS wallet private key. These things tend to happen.

I’ve read someplace that tools can be built for ERC20 tokens to be converted to EOS tokens even after the mainnet launch.

Is this possible? If it is, are you aware of such a solution being built?

Answer (score 2):

> missed the message of registration.

There are a few efforts related to the bootstrapping of the new chain that are intended to address ERC20 holders who have no registered address.  For instance, https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/2669 which intends to put all the tokens in a holding account so that they can be distributed later once an appropriate claim process is approved by the community.  I must stress, the capability of this is in the community's hands so, it is up to the community to decide how this is handled.

> registered and lost their EOS wallet private key

Again, facilities exist for the community's approved system contract to recover these funds.  However, it is far trickier to prove destruction/loss of private key.  In the end, the community will need to come to consensus on how this case should be handled.  From a technical perspective it is handle-able.  The privileged system contract can act as an "root" account and issue transactions. 
 Including issuing a transfer from one account (the lost key) to another.  The expectation is that this contract severely limits the cases where such privilege is used.

Answer (score 0):

no. if you didnt register them and lost your private key then there is no way to recover your coins.