# How to get an account on EOS mainnet?

Tags: accounts, account-name, mainchain

I will start with the description, which *I think* is correct. I am **not sure** about all the steps, so please clarify/correct as much as possible :)

1. If the chain wasn't started yet, and I have some EOS ERC20 tokens, then I need to [register my tokens](https://eos.io/distribution).

   - I need to make sure, to save my private key, which will become an owner key to my account
2. I need to wait for an announcement of snapshot(s) (there can be multiple chains. Each chain may announce their own snapshot)
3. For each chain/snapshot:

   - I should look up what account name was generated and assigned to my public key, which I get during tokens registration, for example in snapshot like this, 2nd column contains `account_name`: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EOSIO/genesis/master/snapshot.csv
   - I can use generated account, and for security reason generate owner  key, upload public-owner key.
   - Using generated account, I can create another account, with more user friendly name, knowing, that there are [restrictions about possible name](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3189).
4. If I had ERC20 EOS tokens and I haven't register them and it is already after a snapshot, then those tokens will be [stuck in limbo](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-solution-being-built-for-those-who-didn-t-register-their-erc20-eos-to/463).
5. If I acquired some EOS-ish tokens (from any chain) on exchange, after chain was already launched

   - Then I need to first create named account, before withdrawing then tokens from the exchange
   - I cannot create an account without help from some other person or some 3rd party service, because ["To create an account we always need a parent account which will create the new one."](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/11/273)
   - Another user/service will be able to create an account for me (I will not have to expose my private keys. I can generate keys on my own, and only provide public keys, which will need to be attached to my future account). The cost of such account will be determined by the network.

Comment: There are a lot more questions here than what the title suggests.. But in any case, regarding point 3. wouldn't the account name generated on all the different chains be the same? As long as they are running the same code, they should generate the same account name, which afaik is based off the ethereum address that you registered.

Answer (score 9):

> *If chain wasn't started yet, and I have some EOS ERC20, then I need to register my tokens. I need to make sure, to save my private key, which will become an owner key to my account*

**Yes**, you need to register your EOS public key against your Ethereum Public key on the EOS smart contract deployed to the Ethereum network.

> *I need to wait for announcement of snapshot(s) (there can be multiple chains. Each chain may announce own snapshot)*

Once tokens are frozen which is June 2nd the final snapshots will be created, they will then be compared and agreed upon block producers for genesis.

> *For each chain/snapshot....*

To be honest I'd chill out, there will be multiple chains booted and perhaps bugs, confusion and all sorts working out which one is mainnet, once conensus is achieved we may see other EOS based blockchains fizzle out etc.

Once things are polished off you can then proceed with creating your account, I believe it will be BitShares style where another party pays for creation of your account in order to register your name yes.

Perhaps a popular faucet will be available for people to register their accounts against.

> *If I had ERC20 EOS tokens and I havn't register those tokens, and it is already after a snapshot, then those tokens will be stuck in limbo.*

You don't register **tokens** but your **public keys** therefore whatever amount of EOS tokens are in your registered Ethereum address at the time of the freeze will be your final balance.

If you've failed to register your public key against an Ethereum account by then, that is not good, however, I believe there might be an ability to create an EOS keypair from your Ethereum private key however this is still a maybe and would have to be honoured by the community, etc.

> *If I acquired some EOS-ish tokens (from any chain) on exchange, after chain was already launched*

I'm a little confused about this one, if you've bought EOS tokens from a classic exchange say like Binance or Kraken (and they are proper EOS tokens not ERC20 tokens which are useless)

The exchange itself might simply pay for creation of your account and you pay them a small fee for doing so, I don't believe they'd handle different EOS networks especially in the early days, I believe they'll wait and be confident they're working with the EOS main net as doing more than the main net just puts more workload on them.