# Account cost on launch?

Tags: mainnetlaunch

What is the estimated account cost on launch.
All data on blockchain must have some RAM allocated, so I understand that creating an account on launch for a registered key will cost some money as well?

Let's say I registered my EOS key and now on launch I will get some random account name. What will be the cost of the account? Let's say on the address one has 0.1 EOS. Is there a risk that the amount will not be enough to register a name or the cost will be so high that it will be the same as the number of EOS related to the key?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked that there are around 400.000 ETH accounts and on my local node a new account takes 2.66 Kb memory.
Is it a safe assuption that the starting memory will be 64 Gb = 64*1024*1024*1024 and the occupied RAM will be 400.000 * 2,66 * 1024, so at launch around 1,6% RAM will be used, so the cost of account creation at launch will be around 0,016 EOS?

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but from my understanding, initial accounts name will be generated by [snapshot-making-software](https://github.com/EOSIO/genesis), and created during launch.

I described my understanding of this here:

[How to get an account on EOS mainnet?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-to-get-an-account-on-eos-mainnet)

So, if you will register your ERC20 EOS tokens before a snapshot, you should end up with generated account, with random-looking name.

You should be able to use that account with your private key generated for purpose of registration. From my understanding, your private key will get a role of owner private key.

One more time, I would like to emphesize, that my assumptions about that are not yet confirmed.

Comment: What will be the cost of this initial account names? Every account needs some RAM to store the data, for RAM you pay with EOS tokens. What will be the cost?